# How catkin is used with ROS2?

Tags: ros, catkin, ros2

I am currently using a ros package called smach with melodic. However, now I need to upgrade my melodic version to crystal to support ROS2 since the project uses DDS. SMACH package is dependent on catkin. Is it possible to create a catkin workspace with crystal (ROS2)?
I tried the following:

```
source /opt/ros/$CHOOSE_ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash
mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
cd ~/catkin_ws/
catkin_make
```

This command gave following result

```
Command 'catkin_make' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install catkin

developer@bionic-base:~/catkin_ws$ sudo apt install catkin
[sudo] password for developer: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
catkin : Depends: python-catkin-pkg but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This error remains even after installing python-catkin-pkg with the command

```
sudo apt-get install python-catkin-pkg
```

I also tried to remove dependency of catkin on Ubuntu

`sudo apt-get install cmake python-catkin-pkg python-empy python-nose libgtest-dev`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems developers use ament to build their packages in ROS2

[Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cUwKVZkrs4&list=PL39WpgKDjDfXbJSoXPlu1qsWIs25oSIGU&index=5)

[Tutorial](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Ament-Tutorial/)

Comment: Broken link for tutorial

Answer (score 0):

source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash